# Why does our Expression Evaluator require "enable 32-bit applications" to be true in IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, vspackage

We have our own Visual Studio package with custom language and debugger .
The Debugger does not work at all unless the apppool its attached to has the property "enable 32-bit applications" set to true.

But why?

configuration is as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{37269d10-8717-49b5-b00a-312a87e63785}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>

<TargetPlatform>v2</TargetPlatform><FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags><OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion><UpgradeBackupLocation></UpgradeBackupLocation><TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion><TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What is your build configuration?

Comment: That is the name of the configuration.. What's inside?

Comment: see the original post above.

Comment: Do you have any 32bit Assembly referenced or any Project, which has "prefer 32bit"?

Comment: the project does not reference any other assembly.

Comment: Tried switching to x64 only?

Comment: I've gotten the target platform from the projects output assembly using powershell and it reports : ProcessorArchitecture : MSIL, which indicates AnyCpu I believe. Which means a 64bit machine should use 64bit JIT.          Could we be on the wrong track? what about Visual Studio itself, isnt it a 32bit app!

Comment: VS itself is 32-bit only - but that has nothing to do with the Output assembly. Try switching the Build process to x64 only.
Perhaps you'll see what's going on then.

Comment: yes just tried it and the same result.

Comment: What exactly happens if you deploy the x64 Application? What error occures?

Comment: The expressions will not evaluate in the watch, we do see some values which look like the C# debugger values, its definitely not ours. Turning the property to True in IIS fixes the issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

The expression evaluator needs to run in the 64-bit process.  A good way to do that is to create a separate, 64-bit-only version of the EE library that the remote debugger proxy can reference.  The COM class of the 64-bit EE factory should be registered under `HKCR\\CLSID`.  You currently use the same guid to register the 32-bit EE factory under `<vsroot>\\CLSID`, and as the value of CLSID under `<vsroot>\\AD7Metrics\\ExpressionEvaluator\\{x}\\{y}\\`, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145343(v=vs.120).aspx).